# How to access the menu of the webapp using HUD?

Tags: unity, hud, webapps

When I open a Web App and try to use the HUD it shows me settings for the browser rather than the app itself. Help?

[image]

[image]

I have this problem with all of my Web Apps not just Google Docs.

Comment: This problem is actually a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity-chromium-extension/+bug/1081305), which means it is offtopic for Ask Ubuntu. Please instead mark yourself as affected on the linked bug and provide the developers there with any information they might need to solve this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed a bug, https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity-chromium-extension/+bug/1081305 , it might be somewhere in bamf (webapps part) or the webapps part of indicator-appmenu,